# Finding nearest points with Chipmunk and cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

Using cocos2d and chipmunk, I try to get the different object around a sprite (for example a bomb) so that I can apply an impulse on these. I first added this on top of my project:

```
#import "ObjectiveChipmunk/ObjectiveChipmunk.h"
#import "CCPhysics+ObjectiveChipmunk.h"
```

And then the code:

```
ChipmunkSpace *space = [_physicsNode space];
cpVect origin = item.position;
for(ChipmunkPointQueryInfo *info in [space pointQueryNearest:origin maxDistance:32.0f filter:CP_SHAPE_FILTER_ALL])
 {
CCLOG(@"Found one body"); 
}
```

I receive this error:

```
 -[ChipmunkPointQueryInfo countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x813cdca0
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should be

```
ChipmunkPointQueryInfo *info=[space pointQueryNearest:origin maxDistance:32.0f filter:CP_SHAPE_FILTER_ALL];
```

`pointQueryNearest` doesn't return array, as you are trying to enumerate.

Cheers.

Comment: I was very tired yesterday for net seen that... thank you very much, in fact what I needed was pointQueryAll and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help